# Problem solving fwith sybols: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Symbol' and 'Equality'

Tags: python, equation, solver, symbolic-math

I have a problem while using solve. I am trying to solve with sybolic math and it works just fine with 2 equations and 2 variables, see the first input and output.

When i use solve with 4 equations and 4 variables i get the error shown in the second input.

Input: for 2 equations and 2 variables

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.linalg as la

a, a0, a1, a2, a3 = symbols('a, a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3')
b, b0, b1, b2, b3 = symbols('b, b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3')
u1, u2 = symbols('u_1, u_2')

a = Eq(0,a0+a1*0+a2*0+a3*0*0)
b = Eq(0,a0+a1*0+a2*b+a3*0*b)

sol = solve((a, b),(a0,a2))
pprint(sol)
```

Output

```
{a₀: 0, a₂: 0}
```

Input: for 4 equations 4 variables

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.linalg as la
a, a0, a1, a2, a3 = symbols('a, a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3')
b, b0, b1, b2, b3 = symbols('b, b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3')
u1, u2 = symbols('u_1, u_2')

a = Eq(0,a0+a1*0+a2*0+a3*0*0)
b = Eq(0,a0+a1*0+a2*b+a3*0*b)
c = Eq(u1,a0+a1*a+a2*0+a3*a*0)

sol = solve((a,b,c),(a0,a1,a2))
```

Output

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-268-eb18268f41f0> in <module>
      6 a = Eq(0,a0+a1*0+a2*0+a3*0*0)
      7 b = Eq(0,a0+a1*0+a2*b+a3*0*b)
----> 8 c = Eq(u1,a0+a1*a+a2*0+a3*a*0)
      9 d = Eq(u2,a+0+a1*a+a2*b+a3*a*b)
      10 

 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Symbol' and 'Equality'
```

I cant figure out this error message, i mean, i use symbols in the version with 2 variables too.

Answer (score 2):

Errors in python tend to be fairly descriptive. A `TypeError` hints you were trying to do some operation with an object type that doesn't support it, e.g., dividing a number by a string. If you ever come across a headscratcher with such an error, start breaking up the offending line to smaller parts and call `type()` to see what type it produces until you find the wrong one. Then you can figure out why it wasn't what you were expecting.

In this case the error says you can't multiply a symbol and an equality. You start with this line

```
a, a0, a1, a2, a3 = symbols('a, a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3')
```

where `a` is a symbol. But then you do

```
a = Eq(0,a0+a1*0+a2*0+a3*0*0)
```

and you've reassigned `a` to an equality. So when it comes time to do `a1*a` in the following line

```
c = Eq(u1,a0+a1*a+a2*0+a3*a*0)
```

you get the error mentioned above. If you assign your equalities to something else, e.g., `A`, `B`, and `C`, you won't have any problems. Assuming that `a`, `b`, and `c` are correct as symbols. It all depends on what equations you're trying to express.

---

You actually have the same problem in your first example, but it doesn't express itself because you don't do any mathematical operations with equalities and symbols.

```
b = Eq(0,a0+a1*0+a2*b+a3*0*b)
```

The reason it works is because you first calculate the RHS and then assign the result of that to the LHS. So the `b` in the equality still refers to a symbol and the expression is legitimate. But after the variable `b` has been reassigned, you can't use it as a symbol anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the great advice. I am kind of new to python, so every little tip helps :)